# Compiling C++ file using MEX

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I need to compile cpp code but I get the following message:

```
Building with 'Xcode Clang++'.
Error using mex
~/code_sparse_group_lasso/linNest.cpp:395:2:
error: no matching function for call to 'linNest'
        linNest(X, y, index, nrow, ncol, numGroup, rangeGroupInd, groupLen,
        lambda1, lambda2, beta, innerIter, outerIter, thresh, outerThresh,
        eta, gamma, betaIsZero, step, reset);
        ^~~~~~~
~/code_sparse_group_lasso/linNest.cpp:276:6:
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'int
*' for 3rd argument; take the address of the argument with &
void linNest(double *X, double* y, int *index, int *nrow, int *ncol, int
*numGroup, int *rangeGroupInd, int *groupLen, double *lambda1, double
*lambda2, double *beta, int *innerIter, int *outerIter, double *thresh,
double *outerThresh, double *eta, double *gamma, int *betaIsZero, double
*step, int *reset)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

I presume the error comes from not correctly specifying the variables. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you "candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'int*' for 3rd argument; take the address of the argument with &". You should definitely try to do this, change your current line:

```
linNest(X, y, index, nrow, ncol, numGroup, rangeGroupInd, groupLen, lambda1, lambda2, beta, innerIter, outerIter, thresh, outerThresh, eta, gamma, betaIsZero, step, reset);
```

to:

```
linNest(X, y, &index, nrow, ncol, numGroup, rangeGroupInd, groupLen, lambda1, lambda2, beta, innerIter, outerIter, thresh, outerThresh, eta, gamma, betaIsZero, step, reset);
```

This makes the types match.

I've looked through the code, `linNest` forwards the `index` pointer to `linSolver`, and that function doesn't use the pointer at all. That is, `index` is not used in your code. I don't know if this is a bug or intentional, but because it's not used, making the change above will certainly not be dangerous. You can also just replace `index` with `nullptr`.